# JASPIC Login with Wildfly 9 Send HTTP Return Code

Tags: authentication, wildfly, http-status-code-403, jaspic

I'm still trying to implement a custom JASPIC login module for Wildfly 9. If the login is successful everything works as expected. But I would expect an HTTP 403 response, if the login is not successful. So I wrote this little test:

```
@Test
public void invalidCredentials() throws IOException, SAXException {
    try {
        WebConversation webConversation = new WebConversation();
        GetMethodWebRequest request = new GetMethodWebRequest(deployUrl + "LoginServlet");
        request.setParameter("token", "invalid");
        WebResponse response = webConversation.getResponse(request);
        fail("Got " + response.getResponseCode() + " expected 403!");
    } catch (final HttpException e) {
        assertEquals(403, e.getResponseCode());
    }
}
```

The result is this:

```
Failed tests: 
    JaspicLoginTest.invalidCredentials:114 Got 200 expected 403!
```

I tried this three options to end the method `validateRequest` of the `ServerAuthModule` after invalid authentication:

```
return AuthStatus.SEND_FAILURE;
return AuthStatus.FAILURE;
throw new AuthException();
```

But none of the above produce a authentication failure HTTP response (403). Is this a Wildfly bug again? Or do I have to produce this return code in an other way?

Comment: a) `FAILURE` is for `ClientAuthModule`s. A SAM's `validateRequest` (vr) may return `SEND_FAILURE` or throw an `AuthException` to indicate an error to its runtime. b) Yes, you must set the HTTP status on the response yourself. What happens otherwise is not-so-standard and not easy to determine beforehand, as vr may be invoked up to 3 times for a single request. c) `AuthStatus` values are not inherently related to HTTP status codes. It's e.g. fine to return `SEND_FAILURE` *and* serve a `200` response to the client. d) Consider reading the spec; it's way more comprehensible than the Javadocs.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, obviously one can take the MessageInfo object and can do such like:

```
public AuthStatus validateRequest(MessageInfo messageInfo, 
                                  Subject clientSubject, 
                                  Subject serviceSubject) throws AuthException{
    //Invalid case:
    HttpServletResponse response =
                        (HttpServletResponse) messageInfo.getResponseMessage();
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
    return AuthStatus.SEND_FAILURE;
}
```